# What's the different between style.left and element.offsetLeft

Tags: javascript, dom

who can tell me what's the different between `style.left` and `element.offsetLeft`, is it same?

Comment: As of 5 years later, there is no answer that actually works to get and set the position of an element!

Answer (score 7):

`element.offsetLeft` Returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the offsetParent node.

`elem.style.left` it's a get of property left of style attribute

Answer (score 5):

You can set the `style.left` - it is user definable and can even remain blank, while `offsetLeft` is always read-only and always has a value - current position.

Answer (score 1):

`element.offsetLeft` returns the distance from the left edge of the node to the parent node in pixels.

`style.left` is the CSS Style for the node, and may be in any of these formats: 
[CSS Unit Formats](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html)

Answer (score 0):

`style` refers to css rules while the other one refers to the actual offset of the element, relative to the parent, no matter if the positioning is caused by css or something else, just as another object, spacing, or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

`style.left` is the left positioning from the viewport screen, whereas `element.offsetLeft` is the left offset position from the outer parent element

Comment: So, the element.style.left = element.offsetLeft + element.parentNode.offsetLeft ?

Comment: @user2155362 That is correct. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pVGdc/9/). Just remember offsetLeft is a readonly value.

Comment: Wrong: style.left is nothing by default as `position` is `static`. It becomes  relative to its static position by `position: relative`, relative to the viewport by `position: fixed`, and relative to is next offset parent by `position: absolute`. So offsetLeft should be its relative position, plus (and this is a guess) margin and transform.

Comment: Why is it so complicated to obtain and set the x position or y position of an element? My experiments all fail.

Comment: @DavidSpector A little late for this observation, but if you assign a value to element.style.left, or element.style.top, you must include the units.  For example, element.style.left = "100px".  I tried just now to find this at mozilla.org, but (oddly) could not.  Instead, look at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_left.asp.